# How to build a personal behavioural chart?

Tags: experimental-psychology, statistics, behavior

The question is realistically in two parts:

1. how could a personal behavioural survey be constructed?
2. are there any existing personal behavioural survey tools available?

The behavioural survey may include questions like:

- Did you feel lethargic today *[yes/no]*?
- How long have you worked out today *[high, medium, low]*?

The survey tool would facilitate statistical analysis by categorically encoding the responses as shown in italics.

It would be appreciated if you could provide ideas as to:

- How could this survey tool be built?
- What questions should be asked?
- How could the responses be quantified and analysed?